# REST WCF inside Windows Service, any drawbacks?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, wcf, rest

I have created a **WCF REST service**, that I **host inside a Windows Service**. 
This WCF REST web service **will be called by a php application**, that will **push a job** to do.

The WCF service puts the new **job in a queue**, and a **worker thread** takes the next job and **executes it**.

This **operation** can take **up to one hour** (in the worker thread)

**WCF returns** to the **client** the **message** that the **job** was **queued**.
At the **end of** every **job**, the worker thread inside **WCF service will call a REST** web service **from php** to **inform** it that the **task is completed**.

I'm not experienced in such scenarios, but I would like to know **if there are any drawbacks to this approach** (Beside scalability issue). My WCF service has set **InstanceContextMode.Single**, which is **mandatory** in my case.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Interesting question but I think it's off-topic for this site. Potentially one for [Programmers StackExchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), or the [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) forums.

Comment: That's because my question is a more conceptual one that practical? I will repost it there if I get no reply here, or if I will get more suggestions to do that. I'm sorry, I did not know programmers.stackexchange until now :)

Comment: @XMight That's basically fine. Consider using TPL Dataflow for executing jobs.

Comment: Sounds as something simple and usual. I wouln't expect any major issues.